# Get a specific tag from a html variable by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a variable in html format. 
i want to get the first IMG tag from it.
is there a simple way to do this?

```
var x = "my name is name picture <img src='/img/pic.a' alt='here first pic'><br/>second pic is here <img src='/img/pic.b' alt='this is the second place'> and the third pic <img src='/img/pic.a' alt='pic 3'> <table><tr><td>first coloumn</td><td>second coloumn</td></tr><tr><td>2first coloumn</td><td>2second coloumn</td></tr></table><br/><p>here is it</p><br><a href='/home'>click here</a>.<br/> end";
var pictureNumber = 1;
var z = x.split("<img")[pictureNumber].split(">");
$("#strImg").val("<img" + z[0] + "/>");
```

the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rpjh3yLo/)

**update**
Thanks to @Tushar for his Advices, it's more simple.
working fiddly per his advice is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rpjh3yLo/8/) 
hope useful for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract by using the regex.

```
/(<img[^>]+>)/gi
```

**Regex Explanation:**

1. `()`: Capturing group to access the matched result
2. `<img`: Matches `<img` literally
3. `[^<]+`: Matches anything that is not `<`
4. `>`: Matches `>`, end of the image tag
5. `gi`: g: Global match, i: case-insensitive match

```js
var x = "my name is name picture <img src='/img/pic.a' alt='here first pic'><br/>second pic is here <img src='/img/pic.b' alt='this is the second place'> and the third pic <img src='/img/pic.a' alt='pic 3'> <table><tr><td>first coloumn</td><td>second coloumn</td></tr><tr><td>2first coloumn</td><td>2second coloumn</td></tr></table><br/><p>here is it</p><br><a href='/home'>click here</a>.<br/> end";
var z = x.match(/(<img[^>]+>)/gi);
console.log(z);

$("#strImg").val(z[0]);
document.getElementById('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(z, 0, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="strImg" size=50>

<br /><br />
<hr />
All Images:
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: thanks, it's using match. someone post an answer and working fiddle, dont know why he deleted it. he give me this --> 
    var z = x.match(/(<img[^>]+>)/g)[1]; 
and it's works and simpler. when i change the number, the img tag which will be taken is changed too

Comment: @akauts This is also the same code, `[1]` at the end gives the first match, in my code `z` is an array containing all the matches. To access first image use `z[0]`, second `z[1]` and so on.

Comment: @akauts I think the regex should be executed only once on the string and then use the matches array to get the result, I guess you're iterating over array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/tsLdorth/

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">my name is name picture <img src='/img/pic.a' alt='here first pic'><br/>second pic is here <img src='/img/pic.b' alt='this is the second place'> and the third pic <img src='/img/pic.a' alt='pic 3'> <table><tr><td>first coloumn</td><td>second coloumn</td></tr><tr><td>2first coloumn</td><td>2second coloumn</td></tr></table><br/><p>here is it</p><br><a href='/home'>click here</a>.<br/> end</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#strImg").val($("#mydiv").children().first()[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

No amazing way of doing it, but one way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var x = "my name is name picture <img src='/img/pic.a' alt='here first pic'><br/>second pic is here <img src='/img/pic.b' alt='this is the second place'> and the third pic <img src='/img/pic.a' alt='pic 3'> <table><tr><td>first coloumn</td><td>second coloumn</td></tr><tr><td>2first coloumn</td><td>2second coloumn</td></tr></table><br/><p>here is it</p><br><a href='/home'>click here</a>.<br/> end";
    $("#strImg").val(getImageTag(x, 2));
});


function getImageTag(x, offset) {
    var imgTag = '';
    var raw = x;

    for (i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
        var imgIndex = raw.indexOf('<img');
        var imgEndIndex = raw.substring(imgIndex).indexOf('>');
        imgTag = raw.substring(imgIndex).substring(0, imgEndIndex + 1);
        raw = raw.substring(imgEndIndex + 1);
    }

    return imgTag;
}
```

Check jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/JoshB1997/rpjh3yLo/6/

The offset is which img tag you want to get (1 = first, 2 = second etc..)
You can also get all image tags first, store in array and then use index to get the images. But with only jQuery I don't think it's possible.

Comment: thanks for your advice, with my code, when i change the number for example I put 2, i could get the second img tag, while yours cannot. I'm new with jquery, i thought there is a simple way with this amazing tool.